# ng-messages not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't get `ng-messages` to work with `ng-repeat`.

```
<form name="testForm">
   <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="text" required />
   <div ng-messages="testForm.text.$error">
      <div ng-repeat="Error in errors" ng-message="Error.type">{{ Error.message }} </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is a example: http://codepen.io/jakej/pen/dXvRdp
First form is using `ng-repeat`.

I've tried both `ng-message` and `ng-message-exp` but none of them works.
Why is `ng-repeat` breaking `ng-message` directive?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have an error on your Json array.

After, you need add a span with ng-message attribute children of the ng-repeat `<div>`

And add `{{` `}}` in your ng-message attribute

It works good

**JS**

```
 $scope.errors = [{
   type: "required",
   message: "Field is required"
 }];
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="Error in errors">
    <span ng-message="{{Error.type}}">{{Error.message}}</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

You don't need to add a children element, only the miss of `{{}}` was important

```
<div ng-repeat="Error in errors" ng-message="{{Error.type}}">                                                                      
    {{Error.message}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ng-repeat and ng-message together, try this way:

```
<form name="testForm">
   <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="text" required />
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div ng-messages="testForm.text.$error">
      <div ng-message="Error.type">{{ Error.message }} </div>
   </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make errors in scope to an array :

```
$scope.errors = [{
   type: "required",
   message: "Field is required"
}]
```